# Could not load file or assembly SysTransaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am developing website that interact with database hosted on SQL Server.

I am getting following error.

*Could not load file or assembly 'SysTransaction, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

*Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SysTransaction, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I googled for same. But didn't found anything. So can anyone guide me what this error is and what should be done to resolve it?

I tried to resolve it by adding System.Transactions. But it did not worked.

Comment: Did you put SysTransaction dll into the BIN foder of your vib site?

Comment: No! I had not added such dlls in BIN folder.

Comment: Try to place it to BIN directory, it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to place it to BIN directory, it will solve your problem